# Can someone explain to me this logic sentence using entailment?

Tags: logic, model-theory

Can someone please explain me what does it exactly mean?

$KB \wedge B^- \not\models\square$

I understand the entailment symbol in this example here : $T \models A $ is if there's no model of  $FS$ in which all members of $T$ are true and A is false.

Negating the $\models$ symbol means the oposite like : $T \models A $ is if there **IS** a model of  $FS$ in which all members of $T$ are true and A is false?... But what exactly means the square symbol in this case? Actually the title of the question is wrong, but I don't know what exactly mean this symbol, neither it's name. And $KB \wedge B^-$ is all formulas in commom between those two sets?

$KB$ is a set of horn clauses(Knowledge base)

$B^-$ is a set of facts(definite clauses without literals in the body) that, ideally, there's no intersection with the $KB$

Thanks.

Comment: Could you give a little more of context? The reference you are using?

Comment: I edited the text, but if it does not help, you can look here http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~dambrobr/classes/cs532/muggleton94inductive.pdf at page 632

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [Resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)) the "square" symbol : $\square$ is usually used to denote the [empty clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clause_(logic)#Empty_clauses), i.e. a contradiction.

The empty clause is always false; thus, the symbol:

> $T \vDash \square$

means that the *theory* $T$ is *unsatisfiable*.

If so,

> $KB ∧ B ⊭ \square$

must mean that the Knowledge base $KB$ plus the set of facts $B$ is *satisfiable*.